# Android pdf and chart generation

Tags: android, pdf, charts, itext, pdf-generation

I am new in Android development. I want to create an Android app which will take input from user, generate a **pie chart** and then export the report in **pdf format**. I am using `iText`([URL](http://www.itextpdf.com/)) and `afreechart` ([URL](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/)) to generate **pdf** and **chart** respectively, but I don't know how to convert the generated chart into image, so that I can insert that image into the pdf. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you convert a perfectly good PDF page into an image before inserting it into another PDF?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
//PdfImportedPage inherits from PdfTemplate
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage( reader, 1 );

Image wrappedImage = new ImageTemplate(page);
// now do whatever you would normally do to position the image where you want it.
```

This does *not* rasterize the imported page.  It's still line art, text, and so forth... whatever it was to begin with.  But now it's wrapped in an `Image` so you can conveniently position it with iText layout classes.

---

Okay.  I just read the docs on AFreeChart.  Apparently you can only draw to a Canvas.

So draw to a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), then call [setBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) to write it to a BitMap, and call [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)'s [compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method to save it as a JPEG or PNG, your call.

iText can handle either of those image formats just fine.  You could probably copy all the pixel information over In The Raw, but this was is considerably less code work on your part.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer, but my problem is a little different, the chart I generated is not a PDF page. JFreeChart, (AFreeChart is the Android wrapper of JFreeChart) has some built in facility to convert the generated chart into image with the help of Java AWT. But Android does not support AWT. So I have to convert the generated chart into image without using AWT. But I don't know how to do that. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone outside adobe can do that yet.  Perhaps a rendering service site a la Google Docs?

Comment: (Disclamer: I'm the founder of Image-Charts) I might want to take a look at https://image-charts.com (a drop-in-replacement for the deprecated Google Image Charts service)